# PHP-Page long loading time due to modal queries and dynamic data from datatables

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Previously I had a post about a query that loads very long due to queries. I was advised to use  `microtime()` to check the parts which loads long. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any problem since everything is loading less than 0.03 seconds. Due to my long troubleshooting, the question got deleted automatically. After a lot of trial and error, I found that the issue was really with the modal having multiple queries.

What happens is that, I load the datatable via query. Now I have a column involving a button that pops-up with dynamic data based on the row selected. The modal is inside the loop within the datatable. The data in my datatable is around 2,000. Now, this modal also populates data which results in this long loading time. I was able to figure it out by mistakenly removed the modal position from the loop resulting making it load faster.

**Scenario Code**

```
<table>
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody>
      //insert query here
      //while loop here
      { -- note the brace
      <tr>
        <td>//random value</td>
        <td> <button>
             <modal>
        </td>        
      </tr>
      } -- note the brace
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Sample Code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#updateProc<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="updateProc<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateProc" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-body">
     <form>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sponsor">Select Value</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="value" >
          <option value="">Select value</option>
            <?php
              $query = mysqli_query($db,"Select id, val from tbl;");
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
               
               //will compare existing to table to showcase selected value
               if ($previous_row_from_query['id']==$row ['id']){   ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $row ['val']; ?></option>
               <?php }
                                                                                        
               else{?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row ['val']; ?></option>
               <?php }
                }?>
              </select>
              <small id="val" class="form-text text-muted ml-2">Choose value.</small>
           </div>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I have `6` queries involved in this modal with the same coding pattern since this is more for editing/updating the data. In the code above, there is also an `if else statement` wherein I used it to compare data from the retrieved value to the existing value to showcase the `selected option`.

Currently, I am trying to find a way for the data to not load earlier on the modal since removing the modal from the `while loop` solves the problem.

Is there a way to simplify the code wherein data will only load if it was called thru button click rather than populating on page load?

Comment: What is the total number of `SELECTs` in this code?  Can any `SELECTs` be combined?  In some situations, this speeds things up by up to 10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I was able to find a solution. Aside from the suggestion above (which I am currently studying), I have found an alternate solution. I found this [tutorial](https://makitweb.com/dynamically-load-content-in-bootstrap-modal-with-ajax/)

So I created another page aside from the main page. For the main page, I modified the button to add a `data-id`. Then added an ajax that will trigger a blank modal and post data from `main` page to the `secondary` page.

**Code main.php**

```
<button data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="userinfo btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Update Info"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i></button> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.userinfo', function(e) {
            var userid = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'secondary.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {userid: userid},
                success: function(response){ 
                    $('.modal-body').html(response); 
                    $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Blank Modal in main**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="empModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Secondary page**

```
<?php
include(dirname(__DIR__).'/db.php');

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
//I inserted a select query here based on userId
//i declared the form here together with the queries

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several patterns you can use here, depending on how your data is *actually* organized.

For example:

```
<option value="">Select value</option>
        <?php
          $query = mysqli_query($db,"Select id, val from tbl;");
```

Above, your query seems to be exactly the same for all rows. So you can pre-calculate it outside the loop, save all rows in an array, and then use the array, just modifying the one line for the loop:

```
          foreach ($results as $row) {
```

In general you might have N different queries out of M different table rows, with M >> N. Then you run the queries beforehand and save them in a sub-array, then choose which array:

```
          foreach ($results['cities'] as $row) {

          foreach ($results[$tableRow['customerType']] as $row {
```

Another possibility is to populate the rows *client side* in Javascript, e.g. with custom libraries like *Handlebars*, or by hand. The advantage is that you can save transmission time for a good chunk of the HTML.

Otherwise, you can do this in AJAX. You *do not* issue any queries *at all*, and just use a button to "unlock" the select. In the table, all relevant SELECTs are replaced by a button which might hold the current value, for show:

```
   <div class="ajaxize" data-query="...SQL..."><button>[value]</button></div>
```

**The query will have to be verified server side** of course. You don't want to get on little Bobby Tables' bad side.

Using e.g. jQuery, you activate class "ajaxize", so when you click on the value, the value is replaced by a SELECT:

```
   $('#tableId').on('click', '.ajaxize button', function() {
        const $div=$(this).closest('.ajaxize');
        const query=$div.attr('data-query');
        $.post("/utilities/ajaxized.php", {
           query: query
        }).then(reply => {
           // Create a select
           const $select = $('select').attr({ name: "selectName" });
           for (let i = 0; i < reply.rows.length; i++) {
               $select.append($('option').attr({ value: reply.rows[i].value }).text(reply.rows[i].text);
           }
           // Replace the button
           $div.html($select);
        });
   });
```

You would also need to save the current value in another data-attribute to be able to pre-select the current value while looping through the OPTIONs.

The PHP "ajaxized.php" will get a query and return a JSON array with the desired rows. You can use `$.get()` to place the reply in the browser cache, to further improve response times.

You can also go down that road fully by using a DataTable library (there are several), that allows you to obtain pageable, responsive datatables with AJAX loading. While (necessarily) slower overall, the result can *appear* to be much faster and be less server-intensive. I personally favour this last approach.

Comment: Hi. About the foreach loop to be saved as an array, is that possible even if the data is located in different tables (in my case 6 tables).

As for the `Select` being replaced by buttons, how do you specifically do this? They didn't teach in school about this. Does that mean that I will integrate a query for the button click?

Comment: You'll have six arrays (`$results['one']`, `$results['two']`,...) and in this case any savings you get will depend on how many queries you ran (e.g. six multiplied 200 rows vs six altogether). If you only had the six queries once each, you save nothing.

For the buttons, yes, you need an AJAX hook on the button, to connect with an appropriate script on the server that will run that one query. The code I included shouldn't be too different from a definitive version (it does require the jQuery library to be installed/loaded).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. I will try to study this and hopefully, it will solve my question. Currently, I have found another method wherein I dynamically load data via Ajax from a different page. Unfortunately, this method only affects the first page of my datatable.

Comment: I'd give a try to https://datatables.net/ . Then you should also look at why those six queries take so long a time; and then there's caching to be considered. It's a lot to chew for a single question :-)

Comment: Yes Sir. Hopefully, I get things working. Thank you again for the response Sir. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome :-) ! Seeing as you're new on S.O., remember to upvote the helpful answers (*hopefully, mine too*) and, if you end up adopting your solution, upvote and accept **your own answer** to indicate that it works (and, of course, amend it if does *not* work), so that whoever chances on this question may know quickly how it went.